# Generate a sequence of words of specific length with spacer characters

Tags: python, r

I have a list of words in a text file and would like to create all possible combinations into a sentence with additional spacers of a particular length (but always shuffling between the alphabets ABCD), and the entire sentence should be only 30-37 characters in length.

```
Text_file 

Computers
laptops
ipads
phones
desktops
TV
kindle
LED
```

So the required sentence will be in the format with words coming from the above list and, the spacer can be combinations of ABCD (either 5 or 10 characters).

AN example sentence will be (this one is 32 char but can be between 30-37)

```
  kindleABCDATVComputersABCDDCABAB
  TVABCDABCDBALEDABCDAlaptopsABCDA
```

The format is
word SPACER(5 or 10 characters) word SPACER(10 or 5 characters) word SPACER (10 or 5 characters) depending on the length of 30-37.

What I tried was using gtools package in R (where n is the number of words in vector, and r is the expected number of words to have, and x is the input). The issue here is being unable to control for length. If am able to do that then I can add spacers of my own.

```
 permutations(n=8,r=2,v=x)
```

Comment: no the entire length of the sequence or the sentence (using words from lists plus the spacers) should have only between 32- 36 characters as shown in the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `permutations` from build-in library `itertools`

```py
import random
import itertools

words = ['Computers', 'laptops', 'ipads', 'phones', 'desktops', 'TV', 'kindle', 'LED']
letters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']

def combinations(words):
    options = set()
    for perm in list(itertools.permutations(words)):
        s = perm[0]
        i = 1
        while len(s) < 30 and i < len(perm):
            s += ''.join(random.choice(letters) for _ in range(5))
            s += perm[i]
            i += 1
        options.add(s)
    return options

print(combinations(words))
```

Result:
*(40320 different combinations)*

```
{
'LEDDDBAAphonesBEDACipadsBACEDlaptops',
'desktopsBEABBkindleEDABEipadsADDABTV',
'TVABEBDComputersBBDBBdesktopsBBECEphones',
'laptopsDDBEBLEDEBEACTVCBAAAphones',
'kindleABDDATVDEDBBComputersCACDDLED',
'kindleEBAECLEDACEDBipadsDEDEAlaptops',
'phonesAEDDDkindleCDEACComputers',
'ComputersADADDphonesECADDipads',
'ipadsDDEADlaptopsBEBBDdesktops',
...
}
```